# Why the shell command is triggered multiple times per POST request instead of one. I am using nodejs and simple-ssh node module

Tags: node.js, express, ssh

How to call a shell script only once per POST request from a express server using simple-ssh node module.
Note: On my first POST request the script/command is executed once but on subsequent request the command is executed multiple times. What is the reason for this behavior?

```
// Snippet that executed once I sent a POST request
  router.post('/testScript', function (req, res, next) {
    res.json({
        'some json': 'To be send'
    })
    next()
  }, function (req, res) {
    ssh.exec('echo $PATH', {
        out: function(stdout) {
            console.log(stdout);
        }
    }).start();
  })
```

The result in my console is:

```
POST /unixscripts/testScript 200 69.202 ms - 34
/usr/lib64/qt-3.3/bin:/usr/local/bin:/bin:/usr/bin

/usr/lib64/qt-3.3/bin:/usr/local/bin:/bin:/usr/bin

/usr/lib64/qt-3.3/bin:/usr/local/bin:/bin:/usr/bin

/usr/lib64/qt-3.3/bin:/usr/local/bin:/bin:/usr/bin

/usr/lib64/qt-3.3/bin:/usr/local/bin:/bin:/usr/bin

/usr/lib64/qt-3.3/bin:/usr/local/bin:/bin:/usr/bin

/usr/lib64/qt-3.3/bin:/usr/local/bin:/bin:/usr/bin
```

See the POST request is triggered once but the script is executed multiple times. Why?
Expected Output every time I sent a POST request:

```
POST /unixscripts/testScript 200 69.202 ms - 34
/usr/lib64/qt-3.3/bin:/usr/local/bin:/bin:/usr/bin
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There seems to be an issue with the `simple-ssh` module wherein the callback is triggered multiple times when used in a loop. This is acknowledged in a github issue [here](https://github.com/MCluck90/simple-ssh/issues/32). Also the module does not seem to be under active development at the moment.

Although I am not sure why it happens, but in case of `simple-ssh` the `exec` function adds a command to stack. Since you are using a common `ssh` connection object, on the next call the older command still exists in the stack. The `start` function then executes the entire stack.

The module internally uses an older version of the `ssh2` module. You can use this module directly in your case.

`npm install ssh2`

```
var Client = require('ssh2').Client;

router.post('/script', function (req, res, next) {
    res.json({
        'some json': 'To be send'
    })
    next()
}, function (req, res) {
    var conn = new Client();
    conn.on('ready', function () {
        conn.exec('echo $PATH', function (err, stream) {
            if (err) throw err;
            stream.on('data', function (data) {
                console.log('STDOUT: ' + data);
            }).on('close', function (code, signal) {
                conn.end();
            })
        });
    }).connect({
        host: 'localhost',
        username: 'user',
        password: 'password'
    });
})
```

Comment: Thanks Stephen the code is working as expected with ssh2 module. Although I am not sure why since simple-ssh uses ssh2 in the backend. Can you shed more light as to why your solution works?

Comment: I've updated the answer with my take on the problem. I haven't used the `simple-ssh` module so without looking at the source I can't be certain. I use `ssh2` though in many of my projects.